# Delete and list out the all models and deployment service from Azure Machine Learning Service using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

How to get all models and deployment service from Azure Machine Learning Service and how to delete it using python.

Is there any way to list, delete all models and deployment services from Azure ML Service using python?

Answer (score 2):

The [Model Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py) has methods to help you accomplish this task. Check out [delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#delete--) and [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#list-workspace--name-none--tags-none--properties-none--run-id-none--latest-false-) methods.

Sample code:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
ws = Workspace.get(name="your_workspace_name",
           subscription_id='your_subscription_id',
           resource_group='your_resource_group')


from azureml.core import Model
for model in Model.list(ws):
    print('name:', model.name, '\nversion:', model.version, '\n')
Model(ws, name = 'model_name', version = 'model_version').delete()


from azureml.core import Webservice
for webservice in Webservice.list(ws):
    print('name:', webservice.name)
Webservice(ws, name = 'webservice').delete()
```

Thanks.

Comment: I run the model list syntax then I got below output.
`Model(workspace=Workspace.create(name='Workspace name', subscription_id='sbscription id', resource_group='resource group'), name=model_name, id=model_name:1, version=1, tags={}, properties={})`

But how to extract the `model_name` from the above output?

Comment: How to get the model_name and service_name?  Can you please give me more info?

Comment: Yes I have created the AML_Workspace and also I have registered the ML models on azure.  but I have lots of models then how can I delete old models.    
How is it possible to remember each and every model name?  Is there any way to delete old models means based on version and date?

Comment: Hello Akshay, I have updated the sample code, so you should be able to list out models and version, and delete accordingly. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your updated above code but I got below error.

    Model(ws, name = str(model.name), version = model.version).delete()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\model.py", line 1235, in delete
    if resp.status_code == 412 and "DeletionRequired" in resp.content:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Please let me know if you have any idea in the above error.

Comment: I believe the error comes from  "DeletionRequired" in resp.content (which is a bit different in the latest version but still generates this error due to unicode?). So you don't get to see the actual exception that tells you that the model is being used. Basically, you have to delete the endpoint (webservice) before you delete the model. The code in the answer is a bit misleading.